# Does an Airflow operator need to return anything in order to function correctly?

Tags: python, airflow

In Airflow, if I create a custom operator class, and use it in a dag, must it actually return anything?

Couple of examples, let's say I create sensor operator (inherits from `base_sensor_operator`) which checks every 5 min for the existence of a file somewhere. Similar to `check_for_wildcard_key()` and how it returns True or False. Does any method I create have to actually have a return statement with this True/False value in order to function? Will the scheduler know to retry this task without a return statement?

Another example is if I create a custom operator (non sensor) that executes SQL code in a database that isn't as common, so I need to create my own operator to connect to that database. So let's say I am using the method `execute_SQL()` inside my custom operator class. I need not have a return value, right? Since the operator object itself inside of a dag file will simply just "run", I don't need to return anything?

I understand sometimes we have a use for `xcom_push` and `xcom_pull`, so it might be good to have return values in case we need to send/receive results between tasks. Is it *good practice* to return something even if it might not be used? Will custom operator classes work without return statements?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, an Operator class does not need to return anything. Actually the main function of an operator is the `execute` method, and most of them does not return anything. Examples: `BranchPythonOperator`, `TriggerDagRunOperator`, `DatabricksRunNowOperator`, etc. They just do the job.

On the other hand, the `poke` method of the sensors need to return `True` or `False` since the `execute` method of the `BaseSensorOperator` calls `self.poke` method, and takes action based on the return value.